# How to draw a line in dc.js using the coordinate system?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, dc.js

How can I add a straight line to a dc.js chart? I want to be able to specify line coordinates in the coordinate system of dc.js, e.g. for a bubble chart, I want to use coordinates relative to its origin, not to the SVG origin.
Also, How can I remove the line again?

Comment: What's the code you're using? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize dc.js easily by using d3 directly. Try something like the following:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {return chart.x()(d.x);})
  .y(function(d) {return chart.y()(d.y);});

var path = line([{x:0,y:1},{x:100,y:1}]);

chart.svg().append("path").attr("d",path)
```

You can set an ID attribute for the path and remove it or change it later with d3 selection on the id or by saving a reference.

Comment: Is there a way to draw `dotted` lines ?